# SharePoint Online Ribbon Custom Action : Pass multiple itemId in CommandAction's Url

Tags: sharepoint-online, ribbon, splistitem, custom-actions, splist

I am developing custom ribbon action using SharePoint hosted app. and this is working fine.When i select any list item and click on custom action then i can get selected list item id.

```
<CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_SendEmailButtonRequest"CommandAction="siteUrl/Pages/test.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={SelectedItemId}&amp;SPListId={SelectedListId}&amp;SiteUrl={SiteUrl}"/>                    
</CommandUIHandlers>
```

**But Problem is**:

In above code *SPListItemId={SelectedItemId}* will pass only single item id. But i want to pass multiple selected item's id through that url.

According to [This Article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfrost/2009/11/08/how-to-display-a-sharepoint-dialog-from-ribbon-button-and-get-selected-item-context/) i tried by adding java-script to `CommandAction`. but i'm getting the following error :

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Install SharePoint Add-in': There were errors when validating the App Package.
```

After googling i found Reason behind this error is

Custom action urls must start with "`http:`", "`https:`", "`~appWebUrl`" or "`~remoteAppUrl`".  The url "`javascript:DoSomething();`" is not in the right format.

So how i can pass multiple selected item's id?

Comment: Greetings! Have You found the soulution for 'SharePoint Online Ribbon Custom Action : Pass multiple itemId in CommandAction's Url'?..